# Checkout Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: magento-2.1, payment

I can't checkout anymore on Magento 2.1.9 and whenever I try to make a payment I get error:

> An error occurred on the server please try processing the order again

and below error in the console:

> VM6525:1 POST http://
>   domain/rest/english/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad
>   Request)

Any Advice how to fix this or debug?

Thanks

Comment: Should check the log.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation required to leave a comment. We are also currently experiencing this issue on 2.1.7 but can't seem to find anything useful in the logs.

Checkout worked fine last week, but this week has returned nothing but 400's.

We are using braintree to process payments, but even options like 'Cash on Delivery' return the 400.

Comment: So, we had a second store view created, that wasn't in use. We deleted it and this 400 error stopped. Nothing else changed, so not sure what that was all about.